# Database Selection

Tags: c#, sql, database

which db is good Access or SQL when it comes to small inventory system?
SQL requires SQL server installed on client machine but do access requires anything or just dotnet framework to work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the system where you are installing the application doesn't have the full version of MS-Office (MS-Access) installed, then you will also have to install the MS-ACCESS Runtime which is available from Microsoft website [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=d9ae78d9-9dc6-4b38-9fa6-2c745a175aed&displaylang=en)

Comment: The link is for MS-Access 2007, but you should be able to download as per the version required by your application.

Comment: DO I have to install any kind of database engine. even if there is ms office .I googled up and they said that I would need Access Database Engine

Comment: If MS-Office is installed then you won't require anything else along with .Net framework.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Express with Entity Framework 4 is a good combination for easy C# development and deployment to client machines.  There's also [SQL server compact](http://robtiffany.com/sql-server-compact/here-comes-sql-server-compact-4-0).

Answer (score 2):

MS Acces should be sufficient for small databases.

Obviously there are a lot of differences between the 2 (triggers, stored procedures, user defined functions to bearly even scratch the surface). But for a small data store/app MS Access is fine.

Once you start to look at transactional requirements, and heavily performant database queries, you will haev to move away from MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

If your data needs to be accessed by other applications in the future, MS-SQL or MySQL might be a better choice. Accessing data from Access might not be so straightforward from non-microsoft platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration is the number of expected users (now and in future). For a single-user system go with Access as SQL Server would be overkill. SQL Server will handle multiple users better and will scale if the number of users is expected to increase in future.

Answer (score 0):

Small inventory system will be a multi user application anyway. 
In this case  a centralized data storage is advised. Which means that it's a clear choice - SQL server.

You can User SQL Server Express, it now supports databases up to 10G which is enough event for a small enterprise for a Year or two...

If You want to avoid SQL server installation, use SQL Compact

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server or another client-server DBMS. There are plenty of good reasons to do that: scalability, security, ease of maintenance and support. The future upgrade path will also be easier whereas using Jet/ACE will generally limit your options or increase the difficulty of porting to another platform later. You can still use Access for the application even if you use a client-server DBMS, so you needn't give up the things you like about Access.